# How to resize controls beyond parent's client area?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have multiple `DataGridViews` separated by splitters (or arranged in a nested `SplitContainers`). I want to be able to resize the outer edge of it to make the whole thing larger than the client area of the parent (which is tabpage in this case). I tried various layout combinations with `SplitContainers`, as well as `Splitters`, but I was unable to achieve this.

Here is what it will look like initially:

[image: Before...]

Here is what I want to achieve:

(when the lower splitter is dragged down, the third grid increases in size and tabpage gets the scrollbar because its children can't fit in its client area, and that tabpage has `AutoScroll` set to `true` of course).

[image: After...]

P.S.: These screenshots are from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), which has this exact feature. When executing the query that yields multiple resultsets, multiple grids are created (one for each resultset) in the client area of Results tabpage. And they aren't limited by the client area of that tabpage, and I want to achieve the same.

Comment: Isn't that just an outer container with a scrollbar, as in "Show scrollbars when needed"?

Comment: I'd try putting your grids in a `FlowLayoutPanel`

Comment: The outer container in this case is a tabpage ("Results"), and yes - it has the "Show scrollbars when needed" (i.e. `AutoScroll`) set to `true`. If I *programmatically* resize its child controls in such way that they occupy more area than its client size, the scrollbar does appear as it should. But the thing here is - I'm unable to make children resizable *manually*. If I place my grids into `SplitContainer` (which will itself be placed into that tabpage), that `SplitContainer` itself will not be resizeable, and that's the problem - I want it to be resizeable.

Comment: I don't know of c#, but in Delphi [a Splitter can be fooled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32553707/757830) to get the desired resizing effect.