# Resize controls with splitter beyond parent's client area

Tags: delphi

I am trying to replicate resizing with splitters as is done by MS SQL Managment Studio like described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909756/how-to-resize-controls-beyond-parents-client-area).

So I have a ScrollBox with many panel-and-splitter pairs, vertically stacked upon each other. When I want to enlarge a panel with the corresponding splitter, it limits the possible growth to the remaining size in the scroll box. I cannot drag the splitter beyond the client size of the scroll box.

Is there anyone that can help me solving this problem?

I have tried to enlarge `VertScrollBar.Range` of the scroll box, without success:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  tDataBlock = class(TComponent)
    fPanel: TPanel;
    fLabel: TLabel;
    fSplitter: TSplitter;
    fOwner: TWinControl;
  published
    property Panel: TPanel    read fPanel   write fPanel;
    property Text: TLabel   read fLabel   write fLabel;
    property Owner: TWinControl read fOwner write fOwner;
  public
    constructor Create(Owner: TWinControl; var t: integer);
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    BlockCount: integer;
    procedure ConfigureScreen;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ConfigureScreen;
var i: integer;
    TotalHeight: integer;
begin
  TotalHeight := 0;
  for I := 0 to ScrollBox1.ComponentCount - 1 do begin
    if ScrollBox1.Components[i] is TPanel then
      TotalHeight := TotalHeight + TPanel(ScrollBox1.Components[i]).Height;
    if ScrollBox1.Components[i] is TSplitter then
      TotalHeight := TotalHeight + TSplitter(ScrollBox1.Components[i]).Height;
  end;
  ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Range := TotalHeight;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  db: tDataBlock;
  t: integer;
begin
  t := 0;
  BlockCount := 0;
  for I := 0 to 3 do begin
    db := tDataBlock.Create(ScrollBox1, t);
    Inc(BlockCount);
  end;
  ConfigureScreen;
end;

{ tDataBlock }

constructor tDataBlock.Create(Owner: TWinControl; var t: integer);
begin
  fOwner := Owner;

  fPanel := TPanel.Create(Owner);
  fPanel.Parent := Owner;
  fPanel.Height := 150;
  fPanel.Top := t;
  fPanel.Align := alTop;
  fPanel.AlignWithMargins := false;
  fPanel.Color := clRed;
  fPanel.ParentBackground := false;
  fPanel.BorderWidth := 0;
  fPanel.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  fPanel.Ctl3D := false;
  fPanel.AutoSize := false;
  fPanel.UseDockManager := false;
  t := fPanel.Top + Panel.Height + 1;

  fLabel := TLabel.Create(self);
  fLabel.Parent := fPanel;
  fLabel.Align := altop;
  fLabel.Caption := inttostr(fPanel.Height);
  fLabel.Font.Size := 10;

  fSplitter := TSplitter.Create(Owner);
  fSplitter.Parent:= Owner;
  fSplitter.Height := 3;
  fsplitter.Top := t;
  fSplitter.AutoSnap := false;
  fSplitter.AlignWithMargins := false;
  fSplitter.MinSize := 1;
  fSplitter.Align := alTop;

  t := fSplitter.Top + fSplitter.Height + 1;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Some asides. TComponent has a virtual constructor that you should override, as a rule. You don't, and you don't call the inherited constructor. Perhaps you really should derive from TObject. And the +1 in your Top calculations appears to be spurious.

Comment: I did that because placing splitters at runtime, they were not at the position i wanted, even if created in the right order. I'm not sure by the way that that is the issue that doesn't allow me to resize panels to a size bigger than the client screen. Can you provide any example eventually?

Comment: I'm reluctant to get into this without all the details. We don't have your dfm. It could also be cut down significantly.

Comment: can post the .dfm too if you'd like to have a look... bottom line, it's just a try at the moment....my goal is to achieve how MS SQL management studio shows panels (resizing them etc) when more than one query are executed in the same TAB.

Comment: Your question does not clearly specify of what you want to achieve so we are forced to guess. So I'm guessing that you perhaps want to be able to resize one of the panels and simply move others up or down respectfully and also resize the ScroollBox client area to fit them all.. If my guess is correct then you would have to abandon the use of splitters. Why? The purpose of splitter is to resize two neighboring components so that one component size is reduced for the same amount that other is enlarged.

Comment: specify what i want to achieve? more than say "resizing panels as MS SQL management does" what should i say? =) yes that is what i would like to get...actually with splitters is working fine....the only problem i have at the moment is that when the client area is full, i'm not able to increase it more than that, even reassigning scrollbar's height etc....and if in your opinion i have to abandon splitters, which alternative would you propose to achieve that?

Comment: I still don't really know what you want. Is the problem at runtime? You want to be able to resize with a splitter at runtime, and are not able to? Is that it?

Comment: See also [How to dynamically create controls aligned to the top but after other aligned controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15623347/757830).

Comment: You cannot expect everyone to have SSMS installed or them wanting to explore its claimed behaviour. If your question isn't clear for someone, then explain it better, of leave it for others to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SilverWarior mentioned, the purpose of `TSplitter` is to divide client area, not to resize the neighboring controls to any size you want. To  achieve your goal you need to change its behavior by some tricks like the one NGLN suggested. But you may experience some side effects if you do so since other parts of code may need `ClientRect` of ScrollBox.

Other option is to simply use mouse events to simulate the behavior of `TSplitter`. I changed your code a little and used a `TPanel` instead. But it’s just a quick start, you may need some more coding, for example to remove the flicker ;).

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  tDataBlock = class(TComponent)
  private
    fPanel: TPanel;
    fLabel: TLabel;
    fResizingPanel: TPanel;
    fOwner: TWinControl;

    IsResizing: Boolean;
    StartHeight, StartY: Integer;

    procedure ResizingPanelMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      X, Y: Integer);
    procedure ResizingPanelMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure ResizingPanelMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  published
    property Panel: TPanel read fPanel write fPanel;
    property Text: TLabel read fLabel write fLabel;
    property Owner: TWinControl read fOwner write fOwner;
  public
    constructor Create(Owner: TWinControl; var t: Integer);
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    BlockCount: Integer;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  db: tDataBlock;
  t: Integer;
begin
  t := 0;
  BlockCount := 0;
  for I := 0 to 3 do
  begin
    db := tDataBlock.Create(ScrollBox1, t);
    Inc(BlockCount);
  end;
end;

{ tDataBlock }

constructor tDataBlock.Create(Owner: TWinControl; var t: Integer);
begin
  fOwner := Owner;

  fPanel := TPanel.Create(Owner);
  fPanel.Parent := Owner;
  fPanel.Height := 150;
  fPanel.Top := t;
  fPanel.Align := alTop;
  fPanel.AlignWithMargins := False;
  fPanel.Color := clRed;
  fPanel.ParentBackground := False;
  fPanel.BorderWidth := 0;
  fPanel.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  fPanel.Ctl3D := False;
  fPanel.AutoSize := False;
  fPanel.UseDockManager := False;
  fPanel.Constraints.MinHeight := 50;
  // fPanel.DoubleBuffered := True;
  t := fPanel.Top + Panel.Height + 1;

  fLabel := TLabel.Create(self);
  fLabel.Parent := fPanel;
  fLabel.Align := alTop;
  fLabel.Caption := inttostr(fPanel.Height);
  fLabel.Font.Size := 10;

  fResizingPanel := TPanel.Create(Owner);
  fResizingPanel.Parent := Panel;
  fResizingPanel.Height := 10;
  fResizingPanel.Align := alBottom;
  fResizingPanel.AlignWithMargins := False;
  fResizingPanel.ParentBackground := False;
  fResizingPanel.Cursor := crVSplit;
  fResizingPanel.OnMouseDown := ResizingPanelMouseDown;
  fResizingPanel.OnMouseMove := ResizingPanelMouseMove;
  fResizingPanel.OnMouseUp := ResizingPanelMouseUp;

  t := fResizingPanel.Top + fResizingPanel.Height + 1;

end;

procedure tDataBlock.ResizingPanelMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  IsResizing := True;
  StartHeight := Panel.Height;
  StartY := fResizingPanel.ClientOrigin.Y + Y;
end;

procedure tDataBlock.ResizingPanelMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if IsResizing then
    Panel.Height := StartHeight + fResizingPanel.ClientOrigin.Y + Y - StartY;
end;

procedure tDataBlock.ResizingPanelMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  IsResizing := False;
end;

end.
```

Comment: No place for Mouse.CursorPos here

Comment: Because it's the current value rather the one associated with the message. Use the latter. It's passed to your event handler. FWIW you repeated the mistakes in the original code. Surely it's worth fixing them.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my code, but there are no side effects: ClientRect is only altered when mouse button is down on splitter.

Comment: @NGLN Actually I did a test. I put a `TPanel` and a `TSplitter` on a `TSCrollBox` and changed the `Splitter1.ResizeStyle` to `rsUpdate` and checked the `ScrollBox1.ClientHeight` in `Panel1.OnResize`. Your code fools the panel as well :).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I removed the use of `Mouse.CursorPos`. You're also right about the mistakes, I just thought correcting them may confuse Tom about the main point since there were plenty of them!

Answer (score 0):

Delphi's default VCL `TSplitter` does not support resizing beyond the size of the parent client rect. (I would opt for such a change if the parent has scroll bars, but that aside.) The reason lies in `TSplitter.MouseDown` wherein a private field `FMaxSize` is set, depending on the `ClientHeight` of the parent.

A solution that might work just for `TScrollBox` is to fool `TSplitter` by returning a different `ClientHeight` of its parent, as follows:

```
type
  TScrollBox = class(Vcl.Forms.TScrollBox)
  protected
    function GetClientRect: TRect; override;
  end;

implementation

function TScrollBox.GetClientRect: TRect;
begin
  Result := inherited GetClientRect;
  if GetCaptureControl is TSplitter then
    Result.Bottom := Screen.DesktopHeight;
end;
```